# IPhone App ajax request Problem

Tags: php, javascript, iphone, ajax, ipad

Hello
 I am using cross domain ajax plugin to send request to server using IPHONE.

But when i complie the code with xcode it is behaving strange.

Some time it send the request to server. some time it doesn't send reuest.

Some time got response from request and some time i am not able to get reponse

Pls. Help

If there is other way to send data to server using javascript then pls. tell me

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If this is a native app, you could use NSURLConnection. Read up on that here: [URL Loading System Programming Guide](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/URLLoadingSystem/Tasks/UsingNSURLConnection.html) If it's a web app, JavaScript is the best way to transmit data bi-direcionally asynchronously. If that doesn't matter to you, you can always use pure PHP and refresh the page each time, although that may not be an optimal user experience.

Comment: THanks for answer.  its a webapp. I  am using javascript ajax to send data to server. but when i complie it in phone gap and then test it then it some time fails to send request and some time fails to got response How can i make it stable....

Comment: sounds like it's an issue with the compiler not turning the js into stable obj-c code. :( unfortunately, I'm not familiar with the framework, but my suggestion would be to ensure you're using the framework's APIs to do your calls, as opposed to bare xhrs or abstractions like jQuery.